# Make DOMParser use Standard mode instead of Quirks mode

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domparser

Just realized that by default, `DOMParser.parseFromString()` creates documents in Quirks mode. Is there a way to make it Standard mode?

```js
console.log(document.compatMode) // 'CSS1Compat'

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<div>Hello World</div>', 'text/html');
console.log(doc.compatMode) // 'BackCompat'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is prepend `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the HTML your parsing

DOMParser will result in the following "document"

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello World</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
console.log(document.compatMode) // 'CSS1Compat'

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<!DOCTYPE html><div>Hello World</div>', 'text/html');
console.log(doc.compatMode) // 'BackCompat'
console.log(doc.documentElement.outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it will if you provide the full HTML markup including the standard doctype of `<!DOCTYPE html>`. If you only provide it an HTML fragment - like `<div>Hello World</div>` - rather than a full page, the engine will create a surrounding doctype and `<html>` and `<body>` for you, and will assume quirks mode.

```js
console.log(document.compatMode);

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div>Hello World</div>
  </body>
</html>
`, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.compatMode);
```